# Find points that are unique between two tables

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have been trying to work out a query that returns the geometry of points that are unique (eg. not supliacte). 
Is there a simple way to perform it in just one query? `geom` is the only common attribute between the tables.
My tables are rather big, about 50000 rows in each.

I need the opposite return to this query:

```
SELECT point1.geom, point2.geom
FROM schema.point1 AS fkb2012 , schema.point2
WHERE ST_Equals(point1.geom, point2.geom) ;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would join both tables in one and then keep only unique rows. If executing your query within PostGIS:

```
WITH temptable AS (
  SELECT geom FROM schema.point1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT geom FROM schema.point2
)

SELECT 
  geom,
  count(*)
FROM temptable
GROUP BY geom
HAVING count(*) = 1 ;
```

Comment: Um, won't your CTE throw out any unique points? I.e. if a point is in point1 but not point2, the ST_equals will get rid of it...

Comment: You are right, I've modified the suggested query.

Comment: Saves me posting exactly that code then ;-)

Comment: Thanks! The query ran very fast. 1.7 sec! The answer is not what I expected, will analyse the result im sure its right.

A thought, one of the layers is MultiPointZ and the other is MultiPoint. Will that might explain a different result that expected? Or does the query take notice of the Z?

Comment: It's important to realize that any use of `UNION ALL`, `GROUP BY`, or the `=` operator works by _bounding box equality_ only.  PostGIS bounding boxes are single-precision floating point, so nearby points will be considered equal.  For example:

`WITH test AS (SELECT unnest(ARRAY[ST_MakePoint(0,1.000001), ST_MakePoint(0,1.000002)]) AS geom)
SELECT geom, count(*) FROM test GROUP BY geom`

returns only a single row.

Comment: I have quite few points that are close (down to cm) sometimes these points return only as a single row as you said correctly. It results in a discrepancy of about 600 points which is OK in my case, but might be something to look up for to others. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work, it might (or might not) be quicker than the union  query way. Make sure you have indexes on your geom columns!

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.geom,b.geom) AS geom
FROM
schema.point1 a
FULL OUTER JOIN
schema.point2 b
ON a.geom = b.geom
WHERE a.geom IS NULL or b.geom IS NULL
```

Comment: I tried the query, it gave me an error COALESCE could not convert type point1 to point 2. Might have something to do with the lack of Z value perhaps as mentioned in my other comment. Will have a look and try sort it out. Thanks!

Comment: I'd guess that that would be the reason. I don't know if you can cast one to another.